# Git restore uncommitted changes of a file restored from deleted

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, restore

guys i have a problem..

i made many changes to a file: `FileController.php` and did not commit it to git

i wanted to perm delete `_ide_helper.php` & `_ide_helper_models.php` but didn't know FileController.php was also selected. when i deleted it git showed that `FileController.php` is deleted now when i restored it the uncommited changes i made was not there :(. done all this in vscode.

as I said when I perm deleted the file. the git in vscode showed that the file is deleted. when I saw it i said wtf no. i clicked on it and restored it now that file is restored but the changes i did and not committed it has been lost

is there anyway to recover  my changes ?? please help anyone

Comment: Files in your working tree are *not in Git* and therefore Git cannot help you with them. Other programs (IDEs like the one from JetBrains, or backup systems like Time Machine on macOS) can, but Git can't. I have no idea about VSCode.

Comment: in such cases always delete to the recycle bin, big binary stuff you can delete permanent, text file delete to the recycle bin, it can even hold multiple version of the deleted file, or use an incremental backup tool to make timed copies of source directories